Partially parallel compiled code
I am working with a series of expressions of the following type:
Compile[
    {x, {v, _Real, 1}},
    Block[
        {x1},
        x1 = Tanh[x] + 3.;
        x1 = Log[x1^3] + Exp[x1]/Log[x1];
        x1*v + 2
    ]
]

The first steps, involving x1, are expensive to calculate and the last step is a simple algebraic function with the vector v.
I want to know if it is possible to compile the code in such a way that the last step is parallelized, analogously to the Parallel`CompiledTable function here (12:56 s). Something like:
Compile[
    {x, {v, _Real, 1}},
    Block[
        {x1},
        x1 = Tanh[x] + 3.;
        x1 = Log[x1^3] + Exp[x1]/Log[x1];
        Parallelize[x1*v + 2]
    ]
]

Up to now I have been using listability of Compile and passing v as a scalar, but it seems inefficient, since the bottleneck is the steps involving x1, which give the same result for all components of v.

Compile is not FunctionCompile.
Just use the option Parallelization of Compile, together with the Option RuntimeAttributes, as described in the documentation.

Naturally FunctionCompile != Compile, but I tried to avoid FunctionCompile declarations because they are a pain to write. The example is just to illustrate the idea. I already said that I am using the normal parallelization of Compile and found it to be not the best for my problem.

Believe me, it is very likely that distributing  x1*v + 2 to several processor won't help you in any way. For "short" vectors (few million entries or less), the overhead of launching several threads is likely to be larger than the single-threaded runtime. For longer vectors the problem is memory bound anyways. I have experience only with shared memory architectures. Typically, on systems with four to eight cores, already one or two processors fully saturate the memory bandwidth. So you won't see n-fold speedup with an n-core system unless n is two-ish. On systems with way more cores there will be even more bottlenecks because not all processors will be able to access all parts of memory with the same speed. If you populated v on a particular core, other cores not in the direct "vicinity" of the first one (speak: not directly wired to the same RAM chip) will have to wait substantially longer before their chunk "arrives" in their cache. Only if the workload were more computation-heavy, one could expect some improvement. And we must not forget that the memory for the result has to be allocated, too. It could be true that most of the runtime goes into this allocation.
The best thing you can do is to encourage the compiler to use vectorization of this portion of code; ideally, one would use vectorized multiply-adds (fma) here. Vectorization is also some kind of parallelization. Most x86 processors nowadays have AVX2 support; each floating-point pipeline can handle fma for 4-vectors of double precision numbers at once; and there are typically two or more such pipelines on each core. Arm64 systems with the NEON instruction set allow the same for 2-vectors. (Which does not mean that they are slower than AVX2 instruction sets, btw.) Mathematica does not give you direct access to these vector instructions---and rightfully so. So, you have to trust in a well-vectorized implementation of scalar-vector implementation x1 * v. Actually, if Compile has access to a good implementation, there is no reason, why top-level Mathematica should not have access to it. And indeed, there seems to be an efficient implementation linked to it:
cf = Compile[{x, {v, _Real, 1}},
   Block[{x1},
    x1 = Tanh[x] + 3.;
    x1 = Log[x1^3] + Exp[x1]/Log[x1];
    x1*v + 2
    ]
   ];

f = {x, v} |-> Block[{x1},
    x1 = Tanh[x] + 3.;
    x1 = Log[x1^3] + Exp[x1]/Log[x1];
    x1*v + 2
    ];

n = 20000000;
v = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}];

a = cf[x, v]; // RepeatedTiming // First
b = f[x, v]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Max[Abs[a - b]]


0.0202595


0.0137273


0.0

Somewhat surprisingly, top-level Mathematica is almost 1.5 times as fast as using the CompiledFunction. (I ran this with Mathematica 14.1 on an Apple M1 Max, so on an arm64 architecture. I am curious whether this performance difference also occurs on x86 machines.) The reason for this discrepancy is not entirely clear to me. CompiledFunction is mostly a wrapper around a library function for x1 * v + 2., so it adds just overhead. Also, CompiledFunction might return by value, not by reference. (So, there might be a superfluous allocation and copy.)  And it could be that the library functions used at top level and in CompiledFunction differ: One might loop over the array once and it might use fused multiply-add, while the other might loop twice over the vector: once for that scalar multiplication and another time for adding 2..

Wow, thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I tested your code on a linux desktop (intel core i5-8400, 2.8GHz) and my timings for a and b where 0.123587 and 0.0625179, respectively. Interestingly, I noticed a spike on all 6 CPU cores when running a and b individually. So I think it really is a difference of code implementation.

I was wondering whether it would be worth it to use the CCodeGenerator`  and pass the code to the compiler manually, since one can give options that optimize the code (I suspect that MMA does not optimize a lot, to keep compilation time small). However I am not sure if it would be worth the effort.

Well, I think the best way for this is to us LibraryLink to create a LibraryFunction. There you can code directly in C++. You can pass in Mathematica packed arrays---even as mutable objects if you like. This is often the best approach for squeezing out the best performance. Btw., I tried that here and even with the -Ofast flag the compiler did not get it faster than the piece of code I ran x1*v + 2. from the front end. The latter could indeed be distributed over all cores. But you see that you don't get proper scaling.

Again, I think that this is due to the fact that the task is memory bound and that two cores saturated the available memory bandwidth. So if it is scheduled on 6 cores will likely be idle (or spinning) until their data finally arrives.

That is impressive, now I am  really curious to know what Mathematica does to make it fast like that.

Could you send me your C++ code? I never wrote anything for Library Link, or C/C++, I wanted to just understand the basic conventions to do that. I tried the Documentation but found it confusing.
